# UISearchBar MinimalStyle Selected Color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My UISearchBar in my UISearchController is acting funny when I tap it.

There are three states to the look of the bar.

## 1: Untapped

[image: Untapped]

## 2: Tapped

[image]

## 3: Tapped with Text  [image]

As you can see, the third one's color is off. Instead of being black like the others, it's tint color is white.

Here's the code chunk containing the setup of the UISearchController & UISearchBar

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchVC"];

self.theSearchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:navController];

self.theSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

self.theSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.theSearchController.delegate = self;
self.theSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
self.theSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.theSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

[self.theSearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

[self.theSearchController.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.theSearchController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.theSearchController.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBG.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.theSearchController.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[self.theSearchController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.theSearchController.searchBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the answer in my storyboard file.

The UINavigationController that the UISearchController was connected to of course had a UINavigationBar. When you tapped and inserted a letter, the UISearchBar blended into the UINavigationBar, inheriting it's color. Once I made the style of the UINavigationBar to Black, the UISearchBar inherited it and it worked.